# Oracle SQL columns naming

Tags: oracle, join, multiple-columns, naming

I'm using Oracle SQL. I have 3 tables which including each one 80 columns with the same columns names. I want to join the tables into a new table, but i supposed to get an error due to a duplicated naming.

I don’t what to rename 240 columns. Is there any other solution?

Here is my tables:

`T1` table

```
c1 int,
c2 int,
..
..
..
c80 int
```

`T2` table

```
c1 int,
c2 int,
..
..
..
c80 int
```

`T3` table

```
c1 int,
c2 int,
..
..
..
c80 int
```

And here is my join:

```
Create table NewTable as
select * 
from T1
   inner join T2
      on T1.id = T2.id
   inner join T3
      on T1.id = T3.id
```

Is there any solution for such as problem? For example - presenting a full column name including table name (t1.c1, t1.c2...).

Comment: replace the wildcard with explicit table.column name and use an alias.

Comment: t3.id=t3.id is suspicious. what's the exact error message as oracle usually dones't care about duplicate columns names, it appends #s however given it usually just adds the next number t2.c1 becomes   t2.c11, but t1.c11 already exists... that might be the problem... in which case without renaming columns or using dynamic SQL a view, or a cte, I think you're out of luck if you want to still do the select *

Comment: The "t3.id=t3.id" was a typo. I fixed it. Anyway, i'm getting "duplicate column name error". The table name prefix wasn't appended.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

select T1.c1, T1.c2, T2.c1 as c1_T2, T2.c2 as c2_T2

etc.
should work.

Edited:
Or maybe you want to UNION the records into one table.  Maybe have an extra column describing the source of the records, if needed to differentiate them.

Comment: I have 240 columns. Your solution doesn’t fit for such as amount of columns.

Comment: You do not have any other chance. Use a macro in your favourite editor if you do not want to type is manually

Comment: At first place, why do you want to join all the columns of all the tables? Seems to be a design issue.

Comment: Maybe you want to UNION the records into the table?